# El banner en Stack Overflow que apunta a SOes enlaza con una URL equivocada

Tags: bug, estado-en-revisión, stackexchange, promoción-del-sitio

Me acabo de topar con un banner de Stack Overflow en español en la página inglesa:

> [image: Más de 410 millones de personas hablan español en el mundo. Ven a compartir tu conocimiento.]

Todo bien, siempre es bueno tener publicidad... ¡Pero apunta a una URL incorrecta! En concreto, apunta a:

- http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjst4YigHa8tAA4_Pxj13NuOVclBDzl7HKt16-e1iT141FA4xuc-ghLBgWX8fUt6qJhiuzgMlpNpEZERJAs78zxt-THZTi2gHqW0ucyzwh2vY_p6Xva5l9HlxiBdQDb4PUFoH9TeVORCOzhb3hZZXIKJZXmj7HUvMWeyYM3vxlAEsXXVvHW2EPMQs7alimClrQPrjsyveskXTmemakCTZ6B7bn2z7BsZNTAoBcRSa4FwxserbUvyOdcYYDAaUeOy-Mbo1mDJQFlQQWL5-iLosLbDgE__AdGF7&sai=AMfl-YSbSB77JqYhbgJZOIu3Y0VdZ-i8hb_x5_7DJ3mbiAJ_Jg7ozqED0cPP9bYYJa6a5Isfc9jXnkjGNc5_eCczmdfsgiND1apB-K02Yo68&sig=Cg0ArKJSzNNmTnmkP1dm&adurl=http://es.stackoverflow.com:80/%3Futm_source%3Dstackoverflow.com%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_campaign%3Dsoes-1%26utm_content%3Dsb-programador&nx=199&ny=53

Que luego me redirige a:

- http://es.stackoverflow.com:443/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=soes-1&utm_content=sb-ven

Quitando la paja, vemos que está apuntando a lo que parece un puerto de desarrolladores:

- http://es.stackoverflow.com:443

Me ocurre en Safari y con la sesión de SOen iniciada. En mi cuenta de SO tengo la opción "custom question lists" activa, por si ocurre como con [otro bug de redirecciones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380000/1983854).

En Chrome y por la línea de comando, sí, me funciona:

```bash
$ curl -v "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjst4YigHa8tAA4_Pxj13NuOVclBDzl7HKt16-e1iT141FA4xuc-ghLBgWX8fUt6qJhiuzgMlpNpEZERJAs78zxt-THZTi2gHqW0ucyzwh2vY_p6Xva5l9HlxiBdQDb4PUFoH9TeVORCOzhb3hZZXIKJZXmj7HUvMWeyYM3vxlAEsXXVvHW2EPMQs7alimClrQPrjsyveskXTmemakCTZ6B7bn2z7BsZNTAoBcRSa4FwxserbUvyOdcYYDAaUeOy-Mbo1mDJQFlQQWL5-iLosLbDgE__AdGF7&sai=AMfl-YSbSB77JqYhbgJZOIu3Y0VdZ-i8hb_x5_7DJ3mbiAJ_Jg7ozqED0cPP9bYYJa6a5Isfc9jXnkjGNc5_eCczmdfsgiND1apB-K02Yo68&sig=Cg0ArKJSzNNmTnmkP1dm&adurl=http://es.stackoverflow.com:80/%3Futm_source%3Dstackoverflow.com%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_campaign%3Dsoes-1%26utm_content%3Dsb-programador&nx=199&ny=53"
*   Trying 172.217.168.162...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to googleads.g.doubleclick.net (172.217.168.162) port 80 (#0)
> GET /pcs/click?xai=AKAOjst4YigHa8tAA4_Pxj13NuOVclBDzl7HKt16-e1iT141FA4xuc-ghLBgWX8fUt6qJhiuzgMlpNpEZERJAs78zxt-THZTi2gHqW0ucyzwh2vY_p6Xva5l9HlxiBdQDb4PUFoH9TeVORCOzhb3hZZXIKJZXmj7HUvMWeyYM3vxlAEsXXVvHW2EPMQs7alimClrQPrjsyveskXTmemakCTZ6B7bn2z7BsZNTAoBcRSa4FwxserbUvyOdcYYDAaUeOy-Mbo1mDJQFlQQWL5-iLosLbDgE__AdGF7&sai=AMfl-YSbSB77JqYhbgJZOIu3Y0VdZ-i8hb_x5_7DJ3mbiAJ_Jg7ozqED0cPP9bYYJa6a5Isfc9jXnkjGNc5_eCczmdfsgiND1apB-K02Yo68&sig=Cg0ArKJSzNNmTnmkP1dm&adurl=http://es.stackoverflow.com:80/%3Futm_source%3Dstackoverflow.com%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_campaign%3Dsoes-1%26utm_content%3Dsb-programador&nx=199&ny=53 HTTP/1.1
> Host: googleads.g.doubleclick.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< P3P: policyref="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/gcn_p3p_.xml", CP="CURa ADMa DEVa TAIo PSAo PSDo OUR IND UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"
< Timing-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: private
< Location: http://es.stackoverflow.com:80/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=soes-1&utm_content=sb-programador
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2019 09:30:37 GMT
< Server: cafe
< Content-Length: 0
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Set-Cookie: IDE=AHWqTUmgIAVauMIGf6_68jywlNU4zLXVUtofk8rGqmGGfDeMysdIPcdtZ-chvBnq; expires=Mon, 11-May-2020 09:30:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.doubleclick.net; HttpOnly
< 
* Connection #0 to host googleads.g.doubleclick.net left intact
```

Comment: Pero parece que redirecciona correctamente a https://es.stackoverflow.com/ ...

Comment: Oh, qué raro, @Pikoh hace un rato no funcionaba.

Comment: @Pikoh en el chat puse [el enlace exacto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49956774#49956774), pues lo de 403 lo pone google ads.

Comment: pegando ese enlace en el chat de The terminal, me lleva bien a SOes

Comment: @Adam thanks for checking this! In case it helps, as I mention in the question, this behaviour makes me remember a similar bug I reported some months ago: [When logged in, pages from tags that are now synonyms do not render](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380000/1983854). The circumstances match: logged in, Safari...

Comment: @fedorqui I don't believe that's related. In this case, our ad serving code is also involved, and it looks like something is misconfigured... somewhere. Looks very similar to [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357303/cross-site-highlights-have-invalid-urls).

Comment: El puerto 443 es el que normalmente se usa para HTTPS en vez de HTTP... De esa manera aunque el protocolo sea HTTP, el navegador lo está obligando a usar una conexión segura con SSL... Por cierto, veo el enlace de Google Ads, casi al final se ve un `.com:80`, que normalmente es el protocolo HTTP.

Comment: @ArtEze gracias por la info. Me sigue pasando este bug